# Wordpress get_the_ID() returns nothing but get_the_title() returns title?

Tags: wordpress

I'm struggling with wordpress templates.  In one of my theme templates I have the following lines

```
<?php
echo get_the_ID(); // displays nothing
echo get_the_title(); // displays "Hello World! this is title"
?>
```

Why does the get_the_ID() return nothing ?  I want the page id of the current page I'm on.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This works within the loop:

```
<?php $this_page_id = get_the_ID(); echo $this_page_id ; ?>
```

Outside of the loop:

```
<?php $this_page_id = $wp_query->post->ID; echo $this_page_id ;?>
```

Comment: oh, how do i get the current id of a page if I'm not in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using wp_query just add this

```
<?php echo $wp_query->post->ID; ?>
```